# why element in std::priority_queue deconstructed so many times?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I am using `std::priority_queue` to do file sort, which i think heap is the best way to sort the stream data.

here is the code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct A { 
  A(int a, size_t b, double c) : a_(a), b_(b), c_(c){}
  ~A() { printf("%d dead\n", a_); }
  int a_; 
  size_t b_; 
  double c_; 
  bool operator <(const A & b) const {
    return a_ > b.a_;
  }
  void show() const {
    printf("%d %zu %lf\n", a_, b_, c_);
  }
};

int main() {
  std::priority_queue<A> q;
  q.push(A(1,2,3));
  q.push(A(3,2,3));
  q.push(A(2,2,3));
  while (!q.empty()) {
    const A & s = q.top();
    s.show();
    q.pop();
  }
}
```

the sorting process is good, but what made me surprised is the element deconstructed so many times as the output is :

```
1 dead
1 dead
1 dead
1 dead
3 dead
3 dead
3 dead
1 dead
3 dead
2 dead
2 dead
2 dead
1 2 3.000000
2 dead
2 dead
2 dead
1 dead
2 2 3.000000
3 dead
3 dead
3 dead
2 dead
3 2 3.000000
3 dead
```

i think every element should deconstruct once, could you explain this?

I think there are only 3 elements constructed, what i expected is only 3 times deconstruct. which i think there is no waste.

Comment: Start by using `emplace(1,2,3)` to avoid constructing and deconstructing a temporary object.

Comment: Every constructed object is desctructed only once, but you don't log all constructors. Specifically, you missed copy constructor and move constructor.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen i can't understand why the first element is deconstructed four times before second element

Comment: @nothingisme Because it has been copied (actually moved) several times - into `push`, into the underlying vector, and so on. See [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aeef9d3479e34c3b).

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
` - wow, just two lines in and you've likely already put off 90% of the people who could answer the question. Please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). I for one won't be reading any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as commenters have pointed out, you are not logging everything you should be logging.
Namely,

- copy construction and move construction are going to create new objects.
  Furthermore
- `std::priority_queue` is an adaptor which uses `std::vector` as a container, and resizing a `std::vector` results in copy/move construction

That being said, the amount of temporary objects that are necessary is *shocking* for GCC.
For `q.push(A(1))`, at the bare minimum, one would expected:

1. `A(1)` needs to be constructed as function argument
2. move construction takes place to move `A(1)` into the underlying `std::vector`
3. the temporary `A(1)` object is destroyed

However, not every standard library delivers this minimum.
Here is a [comparison between libstdc++ and libc++](https://godbolt.org/z/h4vEYccWz) based on the code by @molbdnilo.

```cpp
// libc++
1 created at 0x7ffdde3ba7b4  // A(1)
1 moved into 0x55d082adb2b0  // move into std::vetor
1 dead at 0x7ffdde3ba7b4     // destroy A(1)
```

```cpp
// libstdc++
1 created at 0x7ffeefa52ef8  // A(1)
1 moved into 0x5641c7b9c2c0  // move into std::vector
1 moved into 0x7ffeefa52eb8  // ?!?!
1 moved into 0x7ffeefa52eb0  // ???????
1 move assigned to 0x5641c7b9c2c0 // ????????????
1 dead at 0x7ffeefa52eb0
1 dead at 0x7ffeefa52eb8
1 dead at 0x7ffeefa52ef8     // destroy A(1)
```

In [libstdc++, `push` is just](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/e6413b5dc5b786391802368207ec86945eef2ae0/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_queue.h#L746-L751):

```cpp
void push(value_type&& __x) { // same as in libc++
    c.push_back(std::move(__x));
    std::push_heap(c.begin(), c.end(), comp);
}
```

What makes the difference is that in [on this line](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/e6413b5dc5b786391802368207ec86945eef2ae0/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_heap.h#L215C13-L215C13), the element to be pushed is extracted from the heap back onto the stack:

```cpp
_ValueType __value = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*(__last - 1));
std::__push_heap(__first, _DistanceType((__last - __first) - 1),
                 _DistanceType(0), _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__value),
                 __cmp);
```

And this object is subsequently moved around further.
While this does lead to a surprising amount of objects created, move construction/assignment are overall considered cheap, and this shouldn't have a significant performance impact.